# Whether should computed properties be specified with 'weak' when referencing a weak-ref variable?

Tags: swift, swift2

I've built a tree whose tree nodes look like this:

```
class TreeNode {
    var isRoot: Bool {
        return parentNode == nil
    }
    var childNodes = [TreeNode]()
    weak var parentNode: TreeNode?
    private weak var _rootNodeCache: TreeNode?
    var rootNode: TreeNode? {
        return _rootNodeCache
    }
    private func updateRootCache(node: TreeNode) {
        ...// Implementation doesn't matter.
    }
}
```

I wanna ask should the computed property `rootNode` be specified with `weak`?
It seems ok to run without weak.But I'm afraid that will cause leaks.

Comment: It's been said that computed properties doesn't store any object. What confusing me is: without  the weak specifer is ```_rootNodeCache``` treated as strong referenced through ```rootNode```? If so, are there leaks?

Comment: The Apple documentation states that computed properties do not store values, so `_rootNodeCache` will not be treated as strong reference through `rootNode`, since `_rootNodeCache` is declared as weak. So there wouldn't be leaks and there is no need to specify `rootNode` as weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use `weak` when you have circular references. I understand you have a (parent) `TreeNode` that has `TreeNode` children. The parent has a strong reference to each of the children, and therefore any reference from the child back to the parent must be `weak` or neither will destroy. You have done this by marking `parentNode` as weak.

In the case of `rootNode`, you only need to worry about what it returns. Since it returns `_rootNodeCache`, which is weak, you will not have a circular reference. You can prove this with the code below. Adding or removing weak from `rootNode` makes no difference. However, removing weak from `_rootNodeCache` or `parentNode` results in circular references and deinit not being called.

```
class TreeNode {
    var name: String = ""
    var childNodes = [TreeNode]()
    weak var parentNode: TreeNode?
    private weak var _rootNodeCache: TreeNode?
    var rootNode: TreeNode? {
        return _rootNodeCache
    }
    init(_ name: String, _ root: TreeNode?, _ parent: TreeNode?) {
        self.name = name
        _rootNodeCache = root
        parentNode = parent
        if let parent = parent {
            print("Adding \(name) to \(parent.name)")
            parent.childNodes.append(self)
        }
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit \(name) \(childNodes.count) children")
    }
    func show() {
        print("\(name) has \(childNodes.count) children")
        for child in childNodes {
            child.show()
        }
    }
}

func addChildren(root: TreeNode) {
    let child = TreeNode("child", root, root)
    TreeNode("grandchild", root, child)
}

var root: TreeNode? = TreeNode("root", nil, nil)
addChildren(root!)
root!.show()
root = nil
```